# how to get table cell value within template in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a template in my page

```
<script id="tmplUser" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
   <tr>
      <td>${Name}</td>
      <td>${Email}</td> 
      <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
      <td><img src="images/red_icon.png" name ='removeUser'/>
      </td>                       
   </tr>
</script>
```

I have written the click event handler for the remove user image button in one model.
In that click event I want the selected email of user. How to get that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I might approach the issue. Using a delegated click event I find the closest row to the clicked image and get the second table cells text value. You could improve this by adding a class to the email cell just in case you decide to add other columns before the email column.

```
$('img[name="removeUser"]').delegate('table', 'click', getEmailAddress);

function getEmailAddress() {

  var emailAddress =  $(this).closest('tr').children(':eq(1)').text();

}
```